# How to deserialize JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jackson

I'm making a request to an API from my spring boot backend application. I have been able to serialize my object to JSON and send a POST request to the API. The request goes successful and I've been able to get a response from the server in Json format.The issue arises when I try to deserialize my response to Java object.

> Here is my java Interface.

```
 public interface MyApi{
    ....

    BeneficiaryOnBoardingResponse onBoardBeneficiary(BeneficiaryOnBoardingRequests 
      beneficiaryOnBoardingRequests);
    ....
}
```

> Here is my MyApiServiceImpl

```
public class MyApiServiceImpl extends MyApi{

    private final ConfigFIle configFIle;
    private final OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public MyApiServiceImpl(ConfigFIle configFIle, OkHttpClient okHttpClient, ObjectMapper 
    objectMapper) {
    this.configFIle = configFIle;
    this.okHttpClient = okHttpClient;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}

@Override
public BeneficiaryOnBoardingResponse onBoardBeneficiary(BeneficiaryOnBoardingRequests 
    beneficiaryOnBoardingRequests) {
    AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = getAccessToken();


    String jsonRequest = HelperUtility.toJson(beneficiaryOnBoardingRequests);
    log.info(String.format("Request Body %s", jsonRequest));

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE,
            Objects.requireNonNull(HelperUtility.toJson(beneficiaryOnBoardingRequests)));
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(configFIle.getBeneficiaryOnBoardingEndpoint())
            .post(body)
            .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_STRING, String.format("%s %s",
                    BEARER_AUTH_STRING, accessTokenResponse.getAccessToken()))
            .build();


    try {
        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        assert response.body() != null;
        log.info("====REGISTER CUSTOMER RESPONSE BODY====");
        log.info(String.format("%s", response.body().string()));
        //Deserialize to Java object;
        String json = response.body().string();
        log.info(String.format("%s", json));
        return objectMapper.readValue(response.body().string(), 
           BeneficiaryOnBoardingResponse.class);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
          log.error(String.format("Unable to register customer -> %s", 
          ex.getLocalizedMessage()));
          return null;
    }
}
}
```

> Here is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/customer")
public class CustomerRegistrationController {

   private final MyApi myApi;
   private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
   private final AcknowledgeResponse acknowledgeResponse;

@Autowired
public CustomerRegistrationController(MyApi myApi, 
    ObjectMapper objectMapper, AcknowledgeResponse acknowledgeResponse) 
  {
    this.myApi= myApi;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.acknowledgeResponse = acknowledgeResponse;
}

@PostMapping(path = "/register-customer",produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<BeneficiaryOnBoardingResponse> registerCustomer(
        @RequestBody BeneficiaryOnBoardingRequests 
     beneficiaryOnBoardingRequests
        ){
     return ResponseEntity.ok(
         myApi.onBoardBeneficiary(beneficiaryOnBoardingRequests));
    }
  }
```

This is where the exception occures. I have used jackson to deserialize the Json to a java object.
  `return objectMapper.readValue(response.body().string(), BeneficiaryOnBoardingResponse.class);`

and this is the error from the logs
`2022-03-29 23:19:33.161 ERROR 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed] with root cause`

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you comment out the service layer, is your application starting, this error seems related to servlet, imo

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani Yes. I have other endpoint working well